# How to remove an element from a 2D vector of length N in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a 2D vector of length 5 in MATLAB such as:

```
A=
[1 2;
 3 4;
 5 6;
 7 8;
 9 10]
```

and this the location of certain pixels in an image. By checking a condition such as if `A(:,1) < 2 && A(:,2) > 9` I want to remove two points [1 2] and [9 10] from A and be left with a new A of length 3:

```
newA=
[
 3 4;
 5 6;
 7 8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to do can be done as follow:

```
A(A(:,1) < 2 | A(:,2) > 9, :) = []
```

I think you didn't define your condition properly ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
A=[1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8;9,10];
disp('Original A');
disp(A);
B=[];
j=1;
for i=1:1:size(A)

    if(A(i,1)<2 || A(i,2)>9)
    else
        B(j,:)=A(i,:);
        j=j+1;
    end

end
A=[];
A=B;
disp('updated A');
disp(A);
```

output will be

```
Original A
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
     9    10

updated A
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
```

Comment: What is the efficiency of your code compared to the previous answer ?

Comment: Ahaha I made one solution too, it was 4 strings of code, and when I wanted to post it I saw @R.Bergamote 's answer and understood, that my question have no sense...

Comment: When I posted there was no answer on my window so i just answered.

Comment: @ShvetChakraThanks anyway :)